# How to use yield instead of return

Tags: python

The code below iterates through the numbers ranging between 1 and 5 calling `forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes` function passing it a number. The function takes a number and loops it three times appending each iteration to the `numbers` list which it returns at the end.

```
def forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number):
    numbers = []
    for each in range(number):
        for i in range(3):
            numbers.append(i)
    return numbers


result = []
for number in range(1, 5):
    print number, forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number)
```

Which prints:

```
1 [0, 1, 2]
2 [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
3 [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
4 [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Instead of appending each number to the `result` variable I would like to use `yield`:

```
def forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number):
    for each in range(number):
        for i in range(3):
            yield i
```

Now when I execute:

```
for number in range(1, 5):
    result = forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number)
```

the `result` is not what I expect:

```
1 <generator object forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes at 0x104ebfaf0>
2 <generator object forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes at 0x104ebfaf0>
3 <generator object forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes at 0x104ebfaf0>
4 <generator object forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes at 0x104ebfaf0>
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yield` designates that a function returns a generator object. It conforms to `iterable` interface, so if you want a strict list from it, build the list explicitly:

```
result = list(forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number))
```

or even

```
result = [x for x in forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number):
    for each in range(number):
        for i in range(3):
            yield i
```

---

```
result = []
for num in forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(5):
    result.append(num)
```

or

```
result = list(forEachInRangeThisNumberLoopThreeTimes(number))
```

You have to treat your function like an iterable if you use `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `yield` inside of a function, it becomes a generator, that's why you are getting these outputs.

I'll use a simpler example to explain how to use generators properly.
Let's say we have the following generator:

```
def example_generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2 
    yield 3
```

Now when I'll call `x = example_generator()`, `x` will hold a *generator* not the value 1.

If I want to get the value 1, I would have to

```
x = example_generator()
first_val = next(example_generator())
```

Now `first_val` has the value 1, calling `next()` again, you'll get the value 2. When the generator is exhausted, you'll get a `StopIteration` exception

To avoid `StopIteration` you could just

```
for value in example_generator():
    print(value)
```

and in this case you'll get

```
1
2
3
```

and the for loop will handle the `StopIteration` for you.

If you are looking for getting it as a `list` you are basically losing the advantages of using a generator, but it could be done by

```
list(example_generator())
```

I hope this was a clear enough explanation so you could understand for yourself how to use generators in python. Happy generating!